# Role is granted, still user unable to select from database

Tags: sql, mysql, roles

I have created a **new reader** role with following grants.

| Grants for reader@localhost |
| --- |
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `reader`@`localhost` |
| GRANT SELECT ON `freedb_dfjj01`.* TO `reader`@`localhost` |

Granted this role to readteam1 user:

| Grants for readteam1@localhost |
| --- |
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `readteam1`@`localhost` |
| GRANT `reader`@`localhost` TO `readteam1`@`localhost` |

Still user is unable to access ***freedb_dfjj01***.

```
use freedb_dfjj01;
```

> ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'readteam1'@'localhost' to database 'freedb_dfjj01'